# Strange video appears in background on Safari only

Tags: videos

I hope someone can help me. My site popplekharlamova.com

has this issue in Safari. Not in Chrome or elsewhere, it's taking an age to load and I deleted the video media file ages ago but it's still showing and looks corrupt..

It should be just white background.  I recently had a Wordpress update, it happened after this.

I am no developer, but can build a site with a them, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Any way of getting rid of the video would be great.

Thank you , Jamie

Comment: I don't have Safari browser. Where exactly does the video background show?

Comment: It seems to be tiled, in the background of the whole home page. rest of the site is fine.

As I scroll down it appears in the background all the way to bottom pf page.

Comment: Have you cleared the browsers cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one video file on your page: http://popplekharlamova.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/PK_VIDEO.mp4. It is being loaded on all browsers.

It's hidden in this CSS-block as a `background-image`:

```
<style id="thb-app-inline-css" type="text/css">
.page-id-282 #wrapper div[role="main"] {background-color: !important;background-image:url(http://popplekharlamova.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/PK_VIDEO.mp4) !important;background-repeat: !important;background-attachment: !important;background-position: !important;background-size: !important;}.footer {background-color:#d60000 !important;background-image:url(http://popplekharlamova.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/BACK.jpg)
</style>
```

Delete it from there and you will be fine if you don't have the knowledge to remove it from the code, then you could delete it from the folder, which will solve your problem. However, every browser will then try to load an inexisting file, which isn't really good but won't make any greater harm. Put it on your to-do-list and ask once some developer to delete it for you from the code.

Comment: Thank you!

It's been driving me mad for over a week. To the previous answers, yes I cleared all cache. Thank you for your help.